# Setting component visibility filters within the html/css/js LWC code instead of Web UI

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am looking to set the component visibility filters within the html/css/js LWC code instead of doing this manually in the Web UI.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm understanding you don't want to handle it just from the code but from the App builder only.

There are two ways to do it one using a Component filter from the App builder but it will hide the whole component.

The other way is to use the design attributes where you can specify different types of properties and they will be available on the page. There you need to set the values to hide or show the component or the section under it. No code changes will be required again and again.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="MyComponent">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>

    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>

    <targetConfigs>  
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__HomePage,lightning__RecordPage">
            
            <property name="ShowSection1" type="Boolean" default="false" label="Show Section 1?"/>
            <property name="ShowSection2" type="Boolean" default="false" label="Show Section 2?"/>
            
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
   
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

```
@api ShowSection1=false;
@api ShowSection2=false;
```

```
<template if:true={ShowSection1}>
   <p>showing section 1</p>
</template>

<template if:true={ShowSection2}>
   <p>showing section 2</p>
</template>
```